# Is there a way to check an element from a list for an integer with python?

Tags: python, string, csv, if-statement, integer

I'm importing a CSV file into python and then putting it into a list to be iterated through. I need to check each element in the list for an integer but some of the elements are a mix of letters numbers and spaces, for example: "A2 Honda Civic", "Toyota", and "Nissan 2". These would all be variations of the elements.

My main goal is to pull the numbers out by writing them to a new CSV file which I already have figured out. My original plan was opening the CSV file in excel and finding/replacing a lot of the data to make it more uniform, for example: "AHondaCivic 2", "Toyota" and "Nissan 2". I then wrote a script that parsed by space and I was able to iterate through every element and if it was an integer I would write it to the new csv file and if not it would write NA, but that problem with that was it left me with more NA's than I should have.

Sorry if this is a little unclear its a weird problem to explain but basically I need to check an element in a list that contains both letters, numbers and spaces, to see if there is a number, then write that number to a new file and if there is no number write NA.

Heres some of my code for clarification:

```
import csv

#read and write files
path = '/test/folder/testFile.csv'
new_path = '/test/folder/runFile.csv'

#read the file into a variable
with open(path, newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    w = []
    for row in reader:
        w.extend(row)

with open(new_path,'w',newline='') as nf:
    writer = csv.writer(nf)

    for i in w:
        if i.isdigit()==False:  # if not digit write NA to file
            writer.writerow(["NA"])
        elif i.isdigit()==True: # if digit write that digit to new file
            writer.writerow([i])
```

Here is more code to hopefully clear things up a bit

```
my_path = '/testFolder/test.txt'

my_list = ["Honda 1", "Toyota", "N3 Nissan GTR"]

with open(my_path,'w') as f:
    if any(i.isdigit() for i in my_list):
        f.writelines("True")
```

Where it would write "True" if this code worked, I would instead want it to write the integer, so for "Honda 1" I want it to write 1.

Comment: As an aside, some style advice: instead of `if i.isdigit() == False`, you should use `if not i.isdigit()` similarlly, instead of `elif i.isdigit() == True:` use just `if i.isdigit()`.

Comment: Anyway, can you please provide a [mcve]? What was your input, what is the output you got, and the output you expected/require?

Comment: It is completely unclear what you actuall want, please try to break down you problem in multiple smaller and simpler problems, ask a seperate question for each of them.

Comment: I want to take an element from a list and see if one of the characters is an integer. The input would be would be something like "Honda 1", "Toyota", "Nissan N3 GTR". The output I want from those would be "1", "NA", "3". Sorry for being unclear and thank you for the help! @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for i in w:
    if i.isdigit()==False:  # if not digit write NA to file
        writer.writerow(["NA"])
    elif i.isdigit()==True: # if digit write that digit to new file
        writer.writerow([i])
```

Try this.

```
for i in w:
    try:
      writer.writerow([int(i)])
    except ValueError:
      writer.writerow(["NA"])
```

Comment: This is an interesting point to debate.  In my headspace, exceptions are expensive and should be avoided for normal code paths.  I would far prefer to do the `isdigit` check (with `else` instead of `elif`) and avoid the `try`/`except` thing.  This could be bias from C++, where exceptions are very expensive.

Comment: @TimRoberts Actually, exceptions are a lot cheaper in python than some of those other languages, so you really don't need to avoid them in Python.

Comment: @TimRoberts this is something I am concerned about as my current dataset is 20,000 elements and is expected to be much larger. From what I have been reading it looks like using isdigit() with the not keyword seems to be the more accepted approach

Comment: I suppose it's really personal preference.  It's not going to make a measurable difference in your performance.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yeah pretty much, I mean I wouldn't want to use 50 different exceptions every second, but this was just a quick fix that seemed to work because it will throw a type error if it can't convert it into an integer, but there is more than one way to skin a cat, and an if statement would definitely be more efficient if you could get it working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Instead of this

for i in w:
    if i.isdigit() == False:  # if not digit write NA to file
        writer.writerow(['NA'])
    elif i.isdigit() == True: # if digit write that digit to new file
        writer.writerow([i])

# You can also do this instead

for i in w:
    if not i.isdigit():
        writer.writerow(['NA'])
        continue
    writer.writerow[int(i)]
```